# How to find Minimum Distance between a Point and a Line on sphere

Tags: java, android, math

How to find Minimum Distance between a Point and a Line on sphere.I had this calculation [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/).But it is in 2D. I need on sphere.

Comment: you can ask this quetion on this..it may help to you -http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337055/compute-minimum-distance-between-point-and-great-arc-on-sphere

Comment: Are you talking about an arbitrary point and a line that intersects a sphere? Or an arbitrary point and a line that is tangent to a sphere? In the end, the sphere will not matter. It would help if you gave a little context as to what you're trying to do.  If you're looking for the min distance from an arbitrary point to any point on the outside of a sphere, it's simply ||A-B|| - r, or the distance from vector A to the center of sphere B minus the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Actually I have line or arc connected two locations(lat,lon). Also I have another location. I need to find shortest distance between the third location and the arc or line(which connects first two locations)

Comment: I found formula here under Cross-track distance topic.http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. But it two things dXt and dAt. I confused with which one i want to find?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score -2):

On a sphere, the shortest connection of two points is always on a full circle, i.e. on a circle with maximum radius. You have to find the full circle perpendicular to your line on the sphere that contains the points and compute the arc length appropriately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes, it does answer the question, however it does not solve peoples' homework. If you need clarification on how to approach this problem further, why don't you ask for it in a comment?

Comment: While your answer may help OP to move in the right direction, it doesn't fully [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) the question as you have admitted. A good answer shouldn't include statement like _"If you need more support, I will go into detail."_